# Saving Worksheets, Queries and Results with Ambari

Tags: ambari

​Hello,
I am new to Hive/Hadoop and Ambari.  I am using Ambari through IE 11, to connect remotely.

I have found that:

1) Ambari won't save worksheets or queries - it brings up a window with default name, won't allow me to change it, and locks up for hitting either cancel or save.
2)  Ror the results, when I select 'save as CSV', it gives an unchageable default worksheet name ('Worksheet_1234'), won't allow me to change it, and doesn't provide the path.  When I select to save it to 'hfds', I have no idea of where the results are stored.

Is there any way to save worksheets, and to save the query results to a known location?

Thank you very much!

Barry DeCicco

Comment: I've found the error message displayed by Ambari when I try to save to hfds:

Message:
"Cannot fetch result for job. Job with id: 24016 for instance: Hiverserver2Ranger has either not started or has expired."

Trace:
"      java.lang.Exception: Cannot fetch result for job. Job with id: 24016 for instance: Hiverserver2Ranger has either not started or has expired.

java.lang.Exception: Cannot fetch result for job. Job with id: 24016 for instance: Hiverserver2Ranger has either not started or has expired. "
(more followed)

Comment: For downloading to csv, I get a message in IE that the download failed.  No reason given.